# Getting correct locator for an angular page element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am trying to get the Xpath of a label text in a web page that I am trying to automate. The application is angular based, so there are a lot of angular related stuff on the page.

However, I am trying to automate this using Selenium and Python. The element in question is the error message highlighted in the image -
[image]

The html pertaining to the error message is highlighted in the section below. What would be suitable locator for this element?

I have tried a lot of combinations- using Xpaths and CSS,  but I am coming up empty handed. The absolute xpath - which is

`html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/label` is the only one that works for this case, but I don't want to use it.

Some of the combinations that I have tried - using Xpath's

`//form[@class='ng-untouched']/div[2]/div/label`

`//div[@class='login-inner']/div/label`

both of these don't work and Selenium throws a `NoSuchElement` exception.

Using CSS Selector, I used this -

`element.find_element_by_css_selector(".login-inner.ui-g-12 div label")`

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: //label[text()='password required']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the first two don't work is because you didn't include the full class value for either the form or div element in your xpath.

Try

```
//form[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid']/div[2]/div/label
```

OR

```
//form[contains(@class,'ng-untouched')]/div[2]/div/label
```

Note the use of contains() to match against a partial value. I've found this to be very useful when working against angular.

**But why not simply get the label itself using the text property?**

```
//label[text()='password required']
```

Comment: Well the first and third xpath don't work- and I have no idea why. But the second one, using the contains function work. Thanks for this btw.

Comment: I'm a little surprised the first and third didn't work. Are you using a WebDriverWait to ensure the find isn't performed before the element exists in the DOM?

Comment: Yeah, I am adding sufficient amount of waiting time for the participant to be located. In both of the failed elements, the error was element with this locater could not be found. Although I can check this using the IDE (as mentioned in another answer) to verify if the xpath is indeed correct.

Comment: A trick I use quite often (as I don't like using the IDE) is to use Chrome dev tools (F12). In the console, you can use `$x("<your xpath here>")`. The result will be an array of all elements that match that xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium  IDE.
Record the same test steps and get the highlighted message.
Right click and make a assertion on that text.
Go to the code and check how selenium IDE handles it.
Use the same on your code.

Comment: While this is certainly an option, in my brief experience with the IDE, it often spits out fragile xpaths. **Example: //div[2]/table/tr[5]/td[3]/span**. The problem with something like this is that if a decision is made to rearrange the UI, all tests requiring that xpath locator will break. (They may have improved the IDE since last I used it).